# Install a loader without access to php.ini

Tags: php, encryption

I want to encrypt my php files and it requires a loader to be installed on the host. The thing is I only have access to the FTP and no access to php.ini or any other files except my website files.

So, I'd like to ask if it's possible to install the loader without adding `extension=...` in the php.ini file. I tried searching in Google but only found `dl` which I don't think really helps much in this case.

I want to encrypt the php files because they have my database connection info and I'd like to protect it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. They're typically not plain extensions anyway, but ZendEngine hooks/implementations. (Maybe you should explain *why* you want to "encrypt" your scripts in the first place)

Comment: Added an explanation why. :)

Comment: Well okay. So is this about shared hosting then? (Seriously, rather get a cheap unmanaged VPS from 2-3 USD then. Saner than trying to securing against multi-user hosts. The MySQL/MariaDB server runs under a single uid anyway). Connection infos in a PHP script cannot be read out via HTTP requests. Best to place them atop the DOCUMENT_ROOT though. They're often not even accessible from other user accounts, when suphp/fcgi is used. (If not, then you have an unprofessional hoster. Again: read up on VPS instead; not much more difficult.)

Comment: I just want to secure it so if my FTP is hacked, the files will be encrypted and obfuscated.

Comment: as implied by others - really is no value in doing this.

Comment: I tried obfuscating my files, but the site then won't work.

Comment: if they hack the ftp, the could just replace your files, unlikely to care about tampering with them - also they then would have direct access to the db files- so would not need the username\password to read the data

Comment: Why would they have direct access to the db files? They are not hosted on the same host.

Comment: ok if db is different server then no - but adding something that watches memory so a db call on your site reveals the username\password is easy to do. you seem dead-set on this approach regardless of out advice - so good luck to ya ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you're looking for:
https://github.com/naneau/php-obfuscator

Comment: And if I want to encrypt it as well, isn't it possible to install a loader without php.ini?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by encrypt. Obfuscating is "just" harder for humans to read. Its still 'plain' php.